# How to avoid data from other tab to be visible in current tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using createMaterialTopTabNavigator to display Top Tabs in react native but the data from other tab is visible on the current tab

I have tried to set the container style to `flex 1` and the `flexWrap : 'wrap'` but still the problem persists

[image: Reference Image]

```
const NotificationTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    MobileNotification: {
      screen: MobileNotificationScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: Languages.Notifications.Mobile,
      },
    },
    EmailNotification: {
      screen: EmailNotificationScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: Languages.Notifications.Email,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'MobileNotification',
    tabBarComponent: TopTabBarComponent,
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.SAWhite,
      },
      labelStyle: {
        color: Colors.SAPrimary,
        ...Fonts.Style.normal,
      },
      activeTintColor: Colors.SAPrimary,
      inactiveTintColor: Colors.SASecondary,
      upperCaseLabel: false,
    },
  }
);
```

```
 <View style={styles.flat}>     
    <NotificationTabs navigation={navigation} />
 </View>
```

styles

```
  flat: {
    flex:1
    borderRadius:10
    marginTop: '10%',
    padding: 4,
    backgroundColor: Colors.SAWhite,   
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `overflow: 'hidden'` to the styles

```
  flat: {
    flex:1
    borderRadius:10
    marginTop: '10%',
    padding: 4,
    backgroundColor: Colors.SAWhite,  
    overflow: 'hidden' 
  }
```